# How to fix this error while opening my shiny app after deploying it to shinyapp.io successfully?

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

So I have this simple shiny app code:

```
#setwd("C:/Users/Utilizador/Desktop/script/directory/app1")
#install.packages("shiny")
#if (!require("devtools"))
  #install.packages("devtools")
#devtools::install_github("shiny", "rstudio")
#install.packages('rsconnect')

#library(rsconnect)
#library(shiny)
#rsconnect::setAccountInfo(name='jtadeusfontes', token='50F7221CC3111A15FDBC6A492A5195C5', secret='UtiaRJK4JMOBKeW8na3/i3CxT5CTyVNlYK/QcbSt')
#rsconnect::deployApp("C:/Users/Utilizador/Desktop/script/directory/app1")

library(shiny)
library(rsconnect)
ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput(inputId="taxa", 
            label="Enter the name of the taxon:",placeholder="Example: Cetacea"),
  numericInput(inputId="num",label="Enter a number",value=25),
  plotOutput("bar1")
)

server <- function(input, output){
  output$bar1<-renderPlot({
    title="Random numbers normal distribution"
    hist(rnorm(input$num),main=title)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

But after I deploy it through shinyapps.io, when I try to open the url it returns the following error:

[image]

Thanks for any response in advance

Comment: If you're seeing that error, then I suggest that RSC was not installed or configured correctly. (And you now need to reset your token and secret for your instance of RSC :-) (BTW: you don't need the `rsconnect` package in your app.)

Comment: I'm sorry, what's the RSC? isn't it the rsconnect package?

Comment: RSC is RStudio Connect, sorry, my in-house abbreviation.

Comment: alright, thank you so much for answer, I'll try to install it again

Comment: I'm sorry, again but I forgot a detail that I'm gonna edit in. I did de deployment from shinyapp.io, does that change the scenario?

Comment: BTW: "RStudio Connect" is not `rsconnect` package; the latter is used to deploy to the former, but it also deploys elsewhere (shinyapps). I had assumed that you were trying to push to a RStudio Connect server instance somewhere. I don't know much about shinyapps.io, sorry.